# Website does not download completely

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, download

When I download the tagesanzeiger.ch website with the following code, it does not download completely. Only about a quarter of the content downloads but I receive the "Download completed" message showing that the connection finished loading. Any ideas of any settings I need to change?

```
       - (void)downloadWebsite
        {
        NSString *tagiString = @"http://tagesanzeiger.ch";
        NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tagiString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL];
        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                     delegate:self
                                             startImmediately:YES];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
        {
            [articleData appendData:data];
        }

        - (NSString *)data
        {    
        NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:articleData
                                               encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding];      
        return text;
        }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
     NSLog(@"Download completed");
}
```

Comment: Do you still encounter this issue? It seems fine on my end.

Comment: @verbumdei Yes I still have this issue. It is very odd and I don't know what else to do. Any further ideas are greatly appreciated. When you ran this code did you scroll to the end of the resulting string and compare with the website?

Comment: I saw the resulting string is closed with </html> tag. So I assume the whole html page was downloaded. What is your resulting string?

Comment: And also you need to call your data method from connectionDidFinishLoading. Try not to use the symbol encoding. Use NSASCIIStringEncoding.

Comment: Yes I call the data method from connectionDidFinishLoading as I want to wait until it is truly finished. I also use NSASCIISringEncoding. Interestingly my string also closes with </html> but if I search the string for certain text that is only available at the end of the website it does not show in the string. Is it possible that the website has several </html> tags for some reason and that my download stops at the first one? I have never heard of this case but perhaps there is some special functionality in tagesanzeiger.ch?

Comment: I just checked and it only contains one closing </html> tag. Try NSUTF8StringEncoding and see if you can find the text you want.

Comment: @verbumdei - Thanks for your assistance. Unfortunately the NSUTF8StringEncoding does not work either. Perhaps the website uses some mechanism (PHP?) to determine if it has partially downloaded to a web browser before it sends more information? I still only get about a quarter of the website.

Comment: Maybe you can upload your code somewhere so I can take a look. And also maybe you could let me know the example of text you are looking for.

Comment: @ verbumdei - I am new at this. Where is it the best for me to upload the text for your review? Thanks

Comment: You can use github to upload your code. Or dropbox to upload and share your files.

Comment: @verbumdei - Well, first time, hopefully I did this correctly: https://github.com/petepete717/WebsiteDownloader.git  When you run the program it will NSLog the string that is downloaded. Then you can go onto the website (in this case tagesanzeiger.ch) and just search for any string from a title of an article (written in blue) in the last third of the website and it cannot be found in the string. Thanks for helping! I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: the website seems to be loading some parts with Javascript, hence it is loaded later and can't be obtained initially by the app.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this case? Perhaps first load into a UIWebview instance and then pull the data from there?